# Comparar se dois campos datas são iguais em C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Tenho um `form` e nesse `form` tenho dois campos de data, o `campodata1` e preenchido pelo usuário e o `campodata2` e preenchido pelo banco de dados, agora preciso de um código para comparar se estes dois campos estão com a mesma informação.

Os campos são *string* mesmo estou usando no form o `masktext` para campos data, só preciso comparar pra ver se são iguais pra fazer uma ação.

Segue uma imagem do meu form
[image: Tela como aparece]

Comment: quais os tipos de seus campos datas ? e que tipo de aplicação esta usando ? já tentou alguma coisa?

Comment: Os campos são string mesmo estou usando no form o masktext para campos data, só preciso comparar pra ver se são iguais pra fazer uma ação.

Comment: edite sua pergunta com essas informações e der um exemplo de duas datas.

Comment: tente o seguinte `(campodata1 - campodata2).TotalDays` se o retorno for zero são iguais, se for maior que zero o `campodata1` é superior ao `campodata2` e se o retorno for menor que zero a data `campodata1` é inferior ao  da `campodata2`.

Comment: Isso mesmo mas a comparação e mais simples, só preciso comparar se são iguais só isso...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O que pode fazer é simplesmente converter as datas em formato **STRING** para **DATETIME** e fazer uma comparação normal:

```
DateTime data1 = Convert.ToDateTime(CampoData1.text);
DateTime data2 = Convert.ToDateTime(CampoData2.text);

if (data1 > data2)
{
    /*...*/
}
else if (data1 == data2)
{
    /*...*/
}
else if (data1 < data2)
{
    /*...*/
}
```

Comment: Valeu obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: De nada! Se a resposta ajudou, dá positivo pra ela e marca ela como correta, para ajudar as outras pessoas que chegarem nessa pergunta e ver que está correto.

Comment: Paulo obrigado pela ajuda, mas tenho um problema fui testar agora com o campo data2 em branco e deu u erro de excessão, como posso tratar este erro quando o campo data2 estiver em branco, vc pode me ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
      DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 12, 0, 0);
      int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
      string relationship;

      if (result < 0)
         relationship = "é mais nova que";
      else if (result == 0)
         relationship = "é igual a";         
      else
         relationship = "é depois de";

      Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", date1, relationship, date2);
   }
}
```

Fonte:https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Valeu Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

A solução aceita quebrará a aplicação sempre que alguém entrar um formato errado, assim funciona:

```
if (!datetime.TryParse(CampoData1.text, out var data1)) //faz o tratamento de erro aqui
if (!datetime.TryParse(CampoData2.text, out var data2)) //faz o tratamento de erro aqui
//só pode ir pra frente aqui se não houve erro acima
if (data1 > data2) //faz algo para o maior
else if (data1 < data2) //faz algo para o menor
else //faz algo para o igual
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/Validation2.cs).